# Question about character encoding

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, terminology

If Unicode is a standard and UTF-8 is an ecoding type for that standard why can I save a txt document as either of them in notepad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Microsoft has their own terminology in which they say "Unicode" when the rest of us would say "UTF-16LE".

(or before Windows XP it meant "UCS-2LE")

Comment: +1, but conflating their own implementation with the general term is par for the course in MSFT (e.g. 'a blue icon labeled "Internet"', hint hint)

Comment: Actually I'm not sure whether Microsoft Unicode is always little endian. Did any of the ports of the Windows NT family ever run as big endian?

Comment: What a polite way of saying that Microsoft has screwed up the terminology again! :)

Comment: @tchrist: I practice my diplomacy on SO (-:

Comment: @tchrist: To be honest, I think there isn't a Good Solution either way: had they labeled it "UTF-16LE", they'd have caught flak for being too techy; this way they catch flak for not being techy enough ;)

Comment: Yes in their defence they were early adopters of Unicode and everybody at the time expected it would only ever be 16-bit. It also saved them from changing the name when they upgraded from UCS-2 to UTF-16. But it's made for lots of confusion when Windows people ask question and Unix people answer them, or vice versa.

Comment: Microsoft also says "unicodeFFFE" when the rest of us would say "UTF-16BE".